# Do a recursive search and create a list of files that have a matching pattern

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I have a dictionary file called `dictionary.txt`.

it contains the following example IP addresses:

```
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
3.3.3.3
```

There are many `IP_files.iplists` within this directory, each IP LIST containing many different IP addresses

I would like to search for: `1.1.1.1` and if this string is found within one of the IP LISTS, then output all found IP LIST filenames (e.g. `IP_files_list1.iplists`) to another file that is named after the dictionary search term (eg. `1.1.1.1.txt`)

Ideally then, `1.1.1.1.txt` containing a list of all of the filenames it was found in and `2.2.2.2.txt` would contain a list of all of the IP LIST filenames it was found in.

```
grep -r "1.1.1.1" > 1.1.1.1
```

is about as far as I have come. This creates a file named 1.1.1.1 and lists all of the IPLISTS.iplists file names that "1.1.1.1" is found in.

So 1.1.1.1 looks something like this:

```
IP_files_list1.iplists
IP_files_list2.iplists
IP_files_list_another_list.iplists
```

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing code. Requests for recommendations, tutorials, research, tools, libraries, code are off-topic. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

Use `read` to read from `dictionary.txt`:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /path/to/iplists
while IFS= read -r ip; do
  # get the list of files that contain this ip and save it in a file
  grep -Frlw "$ip" * > "$ip".txt
done < /path/to/dictionary.txt
```

- `-F` treats `$ip` as a string, not a pattern
- `-r` option for recursive search across all files under /path/to/plists
- `-l` to just get the file names containing a match, not the matching content
- `-w` to look for the entire ip (so that `1.1.1.1` won't match `11.1.1.1`

Comment: +1 May I suggest using the `-F` option as well, so that dots will not match any char (not entity sure if this even makes a difference for IP addresses)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

Something like this one liner could work

```
ip='1\.1\.1\.1'; for f in $(find . -type f); do if cat $f | grep -q "$ip"; then echo $f; fi ; done >> $ip.txt
```

You could also surround this with another loop:

```
for ip in '1.1.1.1' '2.2.2.2'; do for f in $(find . -type f); do if cat $f | grep -q "$ip"; then echo $f; fi ; done >> $ip.txt; done
```

Or using your dictionary.txt

```
for ip in $(cat dictionary.txt); do for f in $(find . -type f); do if cat $f | grep -q "$ip"; then echo $f; fi ; done >> $ip.txt; done
```